# GoLang gofmt command

Tags: go, gofmt

gofmt command does not format the flower braces({}).

Code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() 
{
    fmt.Printf("Hello, world\n")
}
```

Output of gofmt hello.go

hello.go:6:1: expected declaration, found '{'
exit status 2

If i put the spaces anywhere it formats it properly.
Does gofmt goes not format the braces?

Comment: Be aware that in Go the curly braces should be used inline with the function declaration!

Answer (score 6):

You have to put the curly brace in the same line of function declaration otherwise your code won't compile because of this syntax error

> **Why are there braces but no semicolons? And why can't I put the opening brace on the next line?**
>
> Go uses brace brackets for statement grouping, a syntax familiar to
> programmers who have worked with any language in the C family.
> Semicolons, however, are for parsers, not for people, and we wanted to
> eliminate them as much as possible. To achieve this goal, Go borrows a
> trick from BCPL: the semicolons that separate statements are in the
> formal grammar but are injected automatically, without lookahead, by
> the lexer at the end of any line that could be the end of a statement.
> This works very well in practice but has the effect that it forces a
> brace style. For instance, the opening brace of a function cannot
> appear on a line by itself.

https://golang.org/doc/faq#semicolons

Answer (score 3):

**your code has syntax error**: put the open curly brace in the same line with function declaration.
and **A program fragment must be a syntactically valid** for using gofmt:

see:  https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/  it says:

> When gofmt reads from standard input, it accepts either a full Go
>   program or a program fragment. **A program fragment must be a
>   syntactically valid** declaration list, statement list, or expression.
>   When formatting such a fragment, gofmt preserves leading indentation
>   as well as leading and trailing spaces, so that individual sections of
>   a Go program can be formatted by piping them through gofmt.

Answer (score 0):

put the open curly brace in the same line with function declaration
maybe you should add gofmt to your editor, it can avoid the problems of code format